# php fetch_object/mysqli_fetch_object is it possible to set/check required fields of row of a result set?

Tags: php, mysqli

Is it possible to set/check required fields of row of a result set from SQL query when using php fetch_object/mysqli_fetch_object?

For example, I describe a class with properties.

```
class MyClass{
  private $field_01; // it is required fields of row of a result set
  private $field_02; // it is required fields of row of a result set
}
```

In this example SELECT contains only one reuired field field_01. Result set does not contain field_02 which should be required for MyClass.

```
$query = "SELECT field_01, field_10 FROM table";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

Now when I do fetch objects - I should get an error that there is no required fields

```
while ($obj = $result->fetch_object('MyClass')) {
   .....
}
```

Is it possible?

I want to apply MyClass to different SQL queries that return different fields. SQL queries can be called in different parent objects. Thus if I use the MyClass object for the query result, then it is necessary that the required properties be written in the query fields.

Comment: Quote manual on `mysqli_fetch_object`: _"Note: This function sets the properties of the object before calling the object constructor."_ - so have your `MyClass` constructor verify all the properties got the required values, and if not, throw an exception ...?

Comment: As I understand it you want to set the value of a property if it is _not_ present in the result? If so you can simply check in the constructor whether it is present, if not you set a default value. Another approach would be to add the property manually inside the query itself as a literal value, something like `SELECT field_01, "foo" as field_10 FROM ...`.

Comment: **For CBroe** If the result of the request has not the required field (_'field_02'_) then the corresponding property (_$obj->field_02_) will be null. But query result can return NULL value for the field (_'field_02'_) in query too. NULL value of  field query (_'field_02'_) is valid

Comment: **For arkascha**
No, I want to know if the Result set of query contains a field name that must be required for the class

Comment: Just forget fetch_object() it's unreliable. Fetch array/stdObject and then populate your custom object

Comment: **For CBroe** I guess I understood. No need to declare the required properties in the class in my case. Then the required properties can be checked in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to declare the required properties in the class to check if the result set of the query contains the names of the fields that should be required by the class. Then the required properties can be checked in the constructor

```
class MyClass{
  public function __construct(){
    // is the result set of the query contains required fields(properties) 
    if(!property_exists($this, 'field_01') or !property_exists($this, 'field_02')){
      ...
    }
  }
}
```